# ¿Cómo obtener queryset entre 3 tablas? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Estoy intentando obtener un QuerySet relacionando 3 modelos.

Mis modelos son estos:

```
class Transaccion(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('id','pedido'),)

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido)
    perfil  = models.ForeignKey(Perfil)
    concepto = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES_CONCEPTO)
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    gastos_gestion = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    comision = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    iva = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    gasto_transferencia = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)

class LineasPedido(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES_ESTADO_PEDIDO)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Pedido(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    f_ped = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    p_prod = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=2)
    p_envio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    cp_nom_producto = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    estado_pedido = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES_ESTADO_PEDIDO, default = CHOICES_ESTADO_PEDIDO[0][0])
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil)
```

---

**Problema:**

Estoy intentando obtener un QuerySet de Transacciones que tienen `LineasPedido.estado = 11` pero no tienen una relación directa y tengo que pasar por el modelo pedido para obtener las transacciones pero de esta forma solo me da las transacciones de un solo pedido y necesito todas las transacciones de todos los pedidos que haya para poder realizar cálculos por agrupaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Sé que ya encontraste la solución a tu problema, pero responderé solo a manera informativa, por si a alguien le sirve la respuesta adicional. Hay una forma de hacer este tipo de consultas cuando las relaciones son "indirectas". Aunque para nuestros modelos, no exista una relación, en realidad existe, solo que el tipo de relación es de muchos a uno.

Django provee una forma de pasar por esas tablas intermedias sin necesidad de hacer varias consultas.

Normalmente, cuando en tus modelos creas una relación de "Uno a muchos" o "ForeignKey" si no agregas un parámetro o atributo llamado `related_name` por defecto Django por `related_name` lo llama `<nombredelaclaseenminuscula>_set`. Al tu no tener eso definido en tu campo cuando lo creas, entonces el `related_name` de tu campo `pedido` en el modelo `LineasPedido` viene a ser igual a `lineaspedido_set` es decir, tu puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
>> # Una shell
>> pedido = Pedido.objects.first()
>> pedido.lineaspedido_set.all()  # esto es un queryset
[<LineasPedido: Producto 2>, <LineasPedido: Producto 1>]
```

Por lo tanto existe una relación de ambos lados de los modelos aún cuando el campo es un `ForeignKey`. Ahora, leyendo un poco la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) acerca de este tipo de consultas ves que termina siendo mucho más fácil por no tener que usar el sufijo `_set`. Y sabiendo que existe esa relación, la consulta quedaría así:

```
>> Transaccion.objects.filter(pedido__lineaspedido__estado=11).distinct()
```

Y esa es la forma fácil de hacer la consulta

> *Nota:*
>   Llevo mucho sin usar Django, te respondo en base a lo que sé y lo que leo de la documentación, no he probado el código que te pasé, puede variar dependiendo a la versión de Django que uses, te pasé la documentación de Django 2.0, y si probablemente la consulta no te corre, el error te dirá cuales son los campos disponibles, es muy probable que te deje hacer la consulta con el `_set` de esta forma: `Transaccion.objects.filter(pedido__lineaspedido_set__estado=11).distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido obtener el queryset de la siguiente forma:

- Por una parte saco lineasPedido con el `estado = 11`

  ```
  linea_pedidos = LineasPedido.objects.filter(Q(estado=11)
  ```
- A partir de éste queryset filtro las transacciones obteniendo los pedido usando `values_list('pedido')`

  ```
  transacciones = Transaccion.objects.filter(pedido__in = lineas_pedidos_pago.values_list('pedido'))
  ```